# Retrieve a hidden form

Tags: c#

I have a hidden form that I want to show. I don't want to create another one like this:

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
```

since I'm using a notification area icon. When opening a new window, I get multiple notification area icons.

So is there a way to show my previously hidden form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

LINQ way:

```
var frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Form1));

if (frm != null)
{
   frm.Show();
}
```

or just iterate over `Application.OpenForms`

```
foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (form is Form1)
    {
         form.Show();
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark is as the correct answer if it works. +1 for LINQ solution :)

Comment: Sorry but where do I do that? Can't seem to find it... I'm new to this =P.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

The NotifyIcon control is housed in the Form, and its events run in the context of the form.  Just use "this" to retrieve it...

```
    private void notifyIcon1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        this.Show();
    }
```

Unless you've used a non-traditional method to house your NotifyIcon?